# How to convert decimal array to string array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

i need to convert Decimal array to string array  .  How to convert decimal[] to string[] ? Can i use

> `Array.ConvertAll()`

method to do this task?

Comment: You'll have to create new array finnaly, so just iterate over this array.

Comment: @Guy: Well Array.ConvertAll does that for you...

Comment: It's not a big effort to try it or read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/exc45z53.aspx. Anyhow, the method will work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I know, your solution is great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx#United%20States%20%28English%29) method. You just need a conversation which can be done easyly with lambda expression.

```
string[] string_array = Array.ConvertAll(decimal_array, x => x.ToString());
```

[`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx#United%20States%20%28English%29) converts an entire array. It converts all elements in one array to another type.

Let's code it;

```
decimal[] decimal_array = new decimal[] {1.1M, 1.2M, 1.3M, 1.4M };
string[] string_array = Array.ConvertAll(decimal_array, x => x.ToString());

foreach (var item in string_array)
{
      Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.GetType(), item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
System.String - 1.1
System.String - 1.2
System.String - 1.3
System.String - 1.4
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/IlrEVS).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) pretty simply - you just need to provide the conversion delegate, which is most easily done with a lambda expression:

```
string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, x => x.ToString());
```

Slightly less efficiently, but more idiomatically and flexibly, you can use LINQ:

```
string[] strings = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Or if you don't actually need an array, and are happy for it to perform the string conversion every time you iterate over it:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

The flexibility here is that `numbers` can change to be *any* `IEnumerable<decimal>` - so if you change to using a `List<decimal>`, you won't need to change this conversion code, for example.

The slight loss in efficiency when calling `ToArray` is that the result of calling `Select` is a lazily-evaluated sequence which doesn't know its size to start with - so it can't know the exact size of output array immediately, whereas `ConvertAll` obviously does.

Comment: +1 for why ConvertAll is more efficient. I was about to ask that but just saw your edit

Comment: How is this possible this questions isn't accepted? :) This is much more detailed.

Comment: @SonerGönül it is probably an attempt to stop Jon's I-get-it-all experience :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
decimal[] decArr = new decimal[5];
// ...
string[] strArr = decArr.Select(d => d.ToString("0.00")).ToArray();
```

Hope this helps